# Devise Not Woking on Heroku Server

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am developing a site with devise gem. Locally it's work but on heroku it is not working. Devise also send confirmation email locally but show nothing on heroku. 
http://incomon.herokuapp.com/

## Heroku Logs

```
2014-02-25T06:05:47.922900+00:00 app[web.1]: [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
2014-02-25T06:05:47.934244+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/users/sign_up host=incomon.herokuapp.com request_id=140cdcbc-c6be-4dbb-bcaf-4ab77f7a76e0 fwd="182.185.250.158" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=76ms status=200 bytes=3573
2014-02-25T06:24:01.826741+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=incomon.herokuapp.com request_id=8c3a9cc2-26c2-441f-b079-601d53025787 fwd="182.185.250.158" dyno=web.1 connect=88ms service=61ms status=304 bytes=1022
2014-02-25T06:24:03.441070+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/users/sign_up host=incomon.herokuapp.com request_id=52e81d7a-cd33-4bf8-9a7c-c85ef57f9ca6 fwd="182.185.250.158" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=15ms status=200 bytes=3573
2014-02-25T06:24:15.053833+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2014-02-25T06:27:07.154449+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=incomon.herokuapp.com request_id=377101eb-2804-46d3-a41d-d0f65fd07726 fwd="182.185.250.158" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=67ms status=200 bytes=1636
2014-02-25T06:27:10.767345+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=incomon.herokuapp.com request_id=8681650f-b5ea-438f-b16a-ccf863e49eab fwd="182.185.250.158" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=228
2014-02-25T06:27:26.227841+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/users host=incomon.herokuapp.com request_id=18c1662e-070f-4cc4-b800-347d2ba8663a fwd="182.185.250.158" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=136ms status=500 bytes=1543
2014-02-25T06:27:26.692345+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=incomon.herokuapp.com request_id=a5491fe3-e684-4b3e-b094-7ca5f096866f fwd="182.185.250.158" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-02-25T06:27:35.903201+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=incomon.herokuapp.com request_id=b826446e-15d7-487f-a93f-86a667a034bb fwd="182.185.250.158" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=304 bytes=848
2014-02-25T06:27:36.553396+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=incomon.herokuapp.com request_id=03a94dbd-2bd0-417a-8333-67a4996605f6 fwd="182.185.250.158" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-02-25T06:27:39.361486+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=incomon.herokuapp.com request_id=d0eae806-b61b-4f84-af8e-d0fc73b30c64 fwd="182.185.250.158" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-02-25T06:27:40.517027+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/users/sign_in host=incomon.herokuapp.com request_id=45769d05-2579-4ada-ae77-330e68f14ea7 fwd="182.185.250.158" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=23ms status=200 bytes=2710
2014-02-25T06:27:40.907652+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=incomon.herokuapp.com request_id=70b3f49a-fa9c-4281-8515-9399636277d3 fwd="182.185.250.158" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=11ms status=304 bytes=133
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970682+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:05:47.869467 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by User::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970682+00:00 
app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970682+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:04:46.336464 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 182.185.250.158 at 2014-02-25 06:04:46 +0000
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970682+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:04:46.444481 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970682+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:04:46.506698 #2]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (23.4ms)
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970682+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:04:46.508911 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 64ms (Views: 30.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970962+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:05:58.328060 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by User::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970962+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:05:59.225468 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 897ms
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970962+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:05:47.932458 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 63ms (Views: 44.8ms | ActiveRecord: 12.0ms)
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970962+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:05:59.223051 #2]  INFO -- :   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (48.4ms)
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970962+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2014-02-25T06:05:59.228397 #2] FATAL -- : 
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970962+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true):
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971156+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: <p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @token) %></p>
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971156+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: 
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971156+00:00 app[web.1]:     4: 
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971156+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971156+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971156+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/user/registrations_controller.rb:16:in `create'
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971915+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:24:03.428963 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 182.185.250.158 at 2014-02-25 06:24:03 +0000
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971156+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:24:01.789030 #2]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (1.0ms)
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971156+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:24:01.784470 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 182.185.250.158 at 2014-02-25 06:24:01 +0000
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971156+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971915+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:24:03.431179 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by User::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971156+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:24:01.786775 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971915+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:24:14.949567 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by User::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971915+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:24:03.437029 #2]  INFO -- :   Rendered user/registrations/new.html.haml within layouts/application (3.3ms)
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971915+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:24:01.790129 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 2.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971915+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:24:03.431343 #2]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"AkkP/F7SZjNfBGPERz80uQLTrnw3gi8P8/gfa6OIOL0="}
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971915+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:24:14.949696 #2]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"AkkP/F7SZjNfBGPERz80uQLTrnw3gi8P8/gfa6OIOL0=", "user"=>{"firstName"=>"Tayyab", "lastName"=>"Zahid", "email"=>"tayyabzahid96@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "userName"=>"tayyab"}, "commit"=>"Sign Up"}
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972148+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:24:15.054836 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 105ms
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972148+00:00 app[web.1]: : BEGIN
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971915+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:24:03.437836 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971915+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:24:14.947905 #2]  INFO -- : Started POST "/users" for 182.185.250.158 at 2014-02-25 06:24:14 +0000
2014-02-25T06:27:46.971915+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2014-02-25T06:24:15.054427 #2] ERROR -- : PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972148+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2014-02-25T06:24:15.056230 #2] FATAL -- : 
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972148+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:07.092850 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 182.185.250.158 at 2014-02-25 06:27:07 +0000
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972148+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/user/registrations_controller.rb:16:in `create'
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972148+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:07.137126 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972620+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:07.141871 #2]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (1.5ms)
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972620+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:07.153884 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 14.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972620+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:12.070759 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 182.185.250.158 at 2014-02-25 06:27:12 +0000
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972620+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:12.080240 #2]  INFO -- :   Rendered user/registrations/new.html.haml within layouts/application (4.0ms)
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972620+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:12.073526 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by User::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972620+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:12.073625 #2]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"w+7mt9jtpi52dlmiEQXc996D+gYN9r/amyAP3RahSuM="}
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972811+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2014-02-25T06:27:26.203898 #2] ERROR -- : PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972620+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:12.081285 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 5.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972620+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:26.097156 #2]  INFO -- : Started POST "/users" for 182.185.250.158 at 2014-02-25 06:27:26 +0000
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972811+00:00 app[web.1]:                               ^
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972811+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'tayy...
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972811+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'tayy...
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972620+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:26.098986 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by User::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972620+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:26.099114 #2]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"w+7mt9jtpi52dlmiEQXc996D+gYN9r/amyAP3RahSuM=", "user"=>{"firstName"=>"Tayyab", "lastName"=>"Zahid", "email"=>"tayyabz@stis.pk", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "userName"=>"tayyab"}, "commit"=>"Sign Up"}
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972811+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:26.225627 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 126ms
2014-02-25T06:27:46.973311+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-25T06:27:46.973311+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/user/registrations_controller.rb:16:in `create'
2014-02-25T06:27:46.973311+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:35.897992 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972811+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'tayyabz@stis.pk' LIMIT 1):
2014-02-25T06:27:46.973311+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:35.896428 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 182.185.250.158 at 2014-02-25 06:27:35 +0000
2014-02-25T06:27:46.973311+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:35.901762 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 2.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972811+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'tayyabz@stis.pk' LIMIT 1
2014-02-25T06:27:46.973311+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:40.499174 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 182.185.250.158 at 2014-02-25 06:27:40 +0000
2014-02-25T06:27:46.973493+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:40.516752 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 11.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972811+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2014-02-25T06:27:26.227535 #2] FATAL -- : 
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972811+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2014-02-25T06:27:46.973493+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:46.964988 #2]  INFO -- : Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 182.185.250.158 at 2014-02-25 06:27:46 +0000
2014-02-25T06:27:46.973311+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-25T06:27:46.973493+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:46.969713 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by User::SessionsController#create as HTML
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970962+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:05:47.869564 #2]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"AkkP/F7SZjNfBGPERz80uQLTrnw3gi8P8/gfa6OIOL0="}
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970962+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:05:58.324570 #2]  INFO -- : Started POST "/users" for 182.185.250.158 at 2014-02-25 06:05:58 +0000
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970962+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:05:58.328309 #2]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"AkkP/F7SZjNfBGPERz80uQLTrnw3gi8P8/gfa6OIOL0=", "user"=>{"firstName"=>"Tayyab", "lastName"=>"Zahid", "email"=>"tayyabzahid96@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "userName"=>"tayyab"}, "commit"=>"Sign Up"}
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972148+00:00 app[web.1]: : BEGIN):
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972148+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972148+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-25T06:27:46.973311+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:35.900793 #2]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (1.2ms)
2014-02-25T06:27:46.973311+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:40.502401 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by User::SessionsController#new as HTML
2014-02-25T06:27:46.973493+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:46.969849 #2]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"w+7mt9jtpi52dlmiEQXc996D+gYN9r/amyAP3RahSuM=", "user"=>{"email"=>"tayyabz@stis.pk", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
2014-02-25T06:27:46.973311+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:40.502524 #2]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"w+7mt9jtpi52dlmiEQXc996D+gYN9r/amyAP3RahSuM="}
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970682+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970682+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:22113
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970682+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970682+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:05:47.866396 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 182.185.250.158 at 2014-02-25 06:05:47 +0000
2014-02-25T06:27:46.970962+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:05:47.931496 #2]  INFO -- :   Rendered user/registrations/new.html.haml within layouts/application (40.6ms)
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972148+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
2014-02-25T06:27:46.972811+00:00 app[web.1]:                               ^
2014-02-25T06:27:46.973493+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-02-25T06:27:40.515825 #2]  INFO -- :   Rendered user/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (8.2ms)
2014-02-25T06:27:46.981461+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/users/sign_in host=incomon.herokuapp.com request_id=870f7f2b-252a-4932-acee-b155b11ff492 fwd="182.185.250.158" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=24ms status=500 bytes=1543
2014-02-25T06:27:47.372924+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=incomon.herokuapp.com request_id=527d7c85-5306-42c5-8880-093b22f2e39f fwd="182.185.250.158" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=133
```

## Error on Webpage

We're sorry, but something went wrong.
   If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

Why this will be happening? Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
```

It looks like maybe you haven't run your migrations yet?

Comment: Can you confirm that the users table exists?

Comment: If the table doesn't exist, then either the migration never got committed or it never got pushed. Easy to miss things like this. :)

Comment: **User Table in db**                                                 Tayyab-MacBook:incomeon T1$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.6230
==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ==============================================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.0171s
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0082s
-- add_index(:users, :reset_password_token, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0091s
-- add_index(:users, :userName, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0123s
==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrated (0.0472s) =====================================